# How to use Ubuntu SSO on Joomla website?

Tags: websites

I'm making a joomla website and I need to use Ubuntu SSO to allow users to login through it, I actually can't find any sort of extension to do so.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems there's no implementation of Ubuntu SSO for Joomla. Would you be able to code an extension by yourself or take an existing OAuth Implementation and adjust it to use the Ubuntu SSO API? You' ll find documentation about [authorisation in general](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/index) and the [token flow](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/index).